# Is the iPhone supposed to save a JPG along with a ProRAW photo?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

I have an iPhone 14 Pro running iOS 16.5.1. I just did a test where I opened the default Camera app on [the iPhone, pressed on "RAW" at the upper right to enable ProRAW](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211965), and then took a photo.

When I looked at the camera roll, I saw that it took a RAW photo. But I thought the iPhone was supposed to save a JPG in addition to the RAW photo. I found an [article](https://www.macstories.net/linked/developer-ben-sandofsky-on-proraw-and-halide-mark-iis-implementation-of-the-new-format/) that confirms that is the case:

> Apple’s Camera app always captures both a ProRAW and JPEG image in one shot when the ProRAW option is picked.

So then I thought maybe the camera roll was hiding the JPG version. I connected the iPhone to my Windows PC, and looked in the subdirectory under the iPhone's DCIM folder. I saw the DNG (ProRAW) photo there, but I did not see any JPG version. I copied the DNG file onto my PC, and only the DNG file was copied over.

I looked at both the Camera and Photos settings, and I do not see anything that would enable/disable the saving of a JPG image along with a ProRAW image.

Am I wrong that the iPhone is supposed to also save a JPG when you take a ProRAW photo?

Comment: idk specifically for ProRAW, but a RAW file usually contains an embedded jpg, which many picture viewers will use to render to screen. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbU5y.png (I'm not actually good enough with [exiftool](https://exiftool.org) to know how to extract it separately… but it's there;)

Comment: You are right. The DNG file does have an embedded JPG that you can extract using ExifTool (`exiftool -b -PreviewImage -w JPG -ext DNG directory_name`).

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone does indeed store a JPEG version of every ProRAW photo taken. The JPEG isn't stored as a separate file though – it exists as a "preview image" inside the DNG file.

At least on photos taken with iOS 17, this "preview" is actually a full-resolution JPEG and includes all metadata that iOS would also write to a JPEG or HEIC image, including all EXIF tags and HDR and depth map channels.

You can extract it using [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) like this:

`exiftool -b -PreviewImage yourfilename.DNG > yourfilename.jpeg`

Update: Oh, I just saw that you also discovered this in your comments!

Your command has the advantage of not requiring shell globbing and input redirection to operate on multiple images (which might not be available on all OSes):

`exiftool -b -PreviewImage -w JPG -ext DNG directory_name`